# Any way to transfer golden keys?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have 10 golden keys on my lower level Commando. However, I want to transfer them to my higher level gunzerker.

Is this possible by any way?

Comment: I thought goldenkeys were on a per account basis? Perhaps they are per computer, as I've added lots of codes and my home pc has like 12, but I just redeemed the 5x from today at work and my work mac has 6 keys.

Comment: I don't know.... I have 1 key on gunzerker and 10 on commando.

Comment: shouldn't it be on the steam cloud, so it shouldn't be set to one computer

Comment: To make it easier, I have added the PS3 tag.

Comment: Tested this. At home `PC` I have 16 golden keys. At work on `Mac` I have 6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Golden keys are tied to your SHiFT account, and cannot be bought, sold, traded, or otherwise used for any purpose but opening the golden chest in Sanctuary.

According to an official source on the [Gearbox forums:](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=147008)

> Keep in mind that you cannot trade or sell Golden Keys, and once you’ve used a Key to open the Golden Chest, that Key is gone for good.

However, the loot you get from the chest is just normal loot and can be traded normally.

If you need more on a character, you might consider keeping track of a [list of SHiFT codes](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Golden_Key) - there are codes for multiple keys that pop up from time to time.

Comment: Is there a reason as to why I have different key counts on the same account?

Comment: @Meraj99, that I don't know anything about.  On the Xbox, you can create multiple profiles and have different characters on different profiles - my wife has about 10 keys and I have more like 25, as we're logging in under different profiles.

Comment: Note that the loot is tied to your level though, if you open the chest on a low level char and trade them to a higher level character the guns are basically junk